# Android Studio : how do 'dependencies' work ? How to update a library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am a newbie with Android Studio.

I integrated this library https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup in my project.

All what I had to to is to follow their instructions and thus to add the following line in the 'app gradle file' (in the 'dependencies'):

```
compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
```

Then click on "sync" at the top right of the Android Studio window of the app gradle file. It works properly ; great !

Nevertheless, I don't really understand the following things :

1) What does "library:1.4@aar" mean ? Is it a single library file ? Where is it located in the folders ?

2) How does Android Studio know where this library is located on my disk ? I copied/pasted the library folder at the root of the folder where I have all my Android projects on my disk ; is it the default location where Android Studio goes to find libraries ?

3) How should I do if I want to modify something in this library and recompile it ? For example, I modified  13sp (in styles.xml) to  30sp, recompiled the library with "./gradlew assembleDebug" (as mentioned on GitHub) but it has no impact on my project even after a clean/build...why ? By the way what does "./gradlew assembleDebug" mean ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you really want to know how it works read the gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

> What does "library:1.4@aar" mean ? Is it a single library file ?

Pulls an [AAR file](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents) from [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/me.gujun.android.taggroup%3Alibrary) or [Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22me.gujun.android.taggroup%22%20AND%20a%3A%22library%22)

In the case of a Maven project, this dependency is expressed in a pom.xml format like so

```
<groupId>me.gujun.android.taggroup</groupId>
<artifactId>library</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
```

As you see, you have the artifact id as "library" and "1.4" is just a version name.

> How does Android Studio know where this library is located on my disk ?

In the `build.gradle` file, you'll have a section like this.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // mavenCentral()
        // mavenLocal()    // Some variant of these. 'jcenter' is the default
    }
```

Depends on your OS, but there is a `.gradle` directory or `.m2` directory in your home folder where all Gradle & Maven dependencies are downloaded.

For example, Gson, for me is at

```
~/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar
```

> if I want to modify something in this library and recompile it ?

Probably too broad for this post, but you would no longer use

```
compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
```

Because that will always use the Github sources, not your changes. You would need to clone the repo and use [`compile project`](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency) feature of Gradle.

> What does "./gradlew assembleDebug" mean ?

Run the [`assemble` task](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks) for the `debug` build type of your project using the Gradle wrapper.

Comment: Could not have said this better myself :)

Comment: As the OP is new to Android, I'd assume he is using a standard project. In this case the library will be fetched from jcenter, not maven.

Comment: @F43nd1r Right, but that Github project linked to Maven Central using those build tag things

Comment: The relevant repositories will be configured outside of the `buildscript` block.

Comment: @Henry I have all three in both `buildscript` and `allprojects`. Don't really know the difference :)

Comment: @cricket_007 everything in `buildscript` is for dependencies used in the build code itself (for example custom plugins). The repositories for dependencies used in the program to be built are configured outside. Putting stuff into `allprojects` is equivalent to specifying it separately in all projects in the multi module build.

Comment: @cricket_007 the used library is also available in jcenter, see https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/me.gujun.android.taggroup%3Alibrary. This is the case with almost all android libraries.